# Efficiently load large .npy files (>20GB) with Keras/Tensorflow dataloader

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, dataloader

I am currently implementing a machine learning model which uses a rather heavy representation of data.
My dataset is composed of images. Each of these images is encoded into a `(224, 224, 103)` matrix, making the entire dataset very heavy. I store these matrixes on the disk and load them during the training.

What I am currently doing right now is using **mini-batches of 8 images** and loading the `.npy` files for these 8 images from the disk during the entire training process. This is slow but it works.

Is there a more efficient way to do it using Keras/Tensorflow (which is what I'm using to code my model)?
I unfortunately couldn't find much about a dataloader that would allow me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to do this.

I will assume that the transformations you are doing to the images to get the final `(224, 224, 103)` matrix is very expensive, and that it's not desirable to do the pre-processing on the data loading. If this is not the case, you might benefit from reading [the tutorial relevant to image processing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images).

I suggest you use a python generator to read the data, and to use `tf.data` to create a data pipeline to feed these `.npy` files to your model. The basic idea is very simple. you use a wrapper to ingest data from a generator that will read the files as needed. The relevant documentation and examples are [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators).

Now, once you get that working, I think it would be a good idea for you to [optimize](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) your pipeline, especially if you're planning to train in multiple GPUs or multiple computers.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for

Comment: @Megastore could you please show you solution?